# Deletion from a linked list returns garbage value

Tags: c++

Class Listnode is a minimal implementation of linked list.
It has basic operations such as Inserting at the head, tail and at a specific position. It also has deletion implementation.
So far delete at head and delete at tail works but deleting at a specific index result to it replacing the value with garbage.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
class ListNode {
        friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const ListNode &n ) {
        ListNode *temp = n.head;
        os << "[ ";
        while ( temp != n.tail ) {
            os << temp->data << ", ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        os << temp->data << " ]";
        return os;
    }
    private:
        ListNode *prev;
        int data;
        ListNode *next;
        int sizeOfList;
        ListNode *head, *tail;

        bool outOfBound( int index, int size ) {
                if ( index >= sizeOfList || index < 0 ) 
                    return true;
                return false;
        }

    public:
        ListNode() : prev(nullptr), data(0), next(nullptr), sizeOfList(0), head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}

        void create( int val ) {
            ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
            newNode->data = val;
            if( head == nullptr )
                head = tail = newNode;
            else {
                tail->next = newNode;
                newNode->prev = tail;
                tail = newNode;
            }
            ++sizeOfList;
        }
        
        int size() { return sizeOfList; }
        void insertAtHead( int val ) {
            ListNode *newNode  = new ListNode;
            newNode->data = val;
            newNode->next = head;
            head->prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            ++sizeOfList;
        }

        void insertAtTail( int val ) {
            ListNode *newNode  = new ListNode;
            newNode->data = val;
            newNode->prev = tail;
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            ++sizeOfList;
        }
        void insert( int index, int val ) {
            if( index == 0 ) {
                insertAtHead( val );
                return;
            }
            if( index == sizeOfList - 1 ) {
                insertAtTail( val );
                return;
            }
            if(outOfBound( index, sizeOfList ) )
                throw std::out_of_range("Exception: Out of Range.");
            int i = 1;
            ListNode *temp = head;
            ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
            newNode->data = val;
            while( i != index ) {
                temp = temp->next;
                ++i;
            }
            newNode->prev = temp;
            newNode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = newNode;
            temp->next->prev = newNode;
            ++sizeOfList;
        }
        void deleteAtHead() {
            ListNode *temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            head->prev = nullptr;
            delete temp;
            --sizeOfList;
        }
        void deleteAtTail() {
            ListNode *temp = tail;
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = nullptr;
            delete temp;
            --sizeOfList;
        }
        void erase( int index ) {
            if( index == 0 ) {
                deleteAtHead();
                return;
            }
            if( index == sizeOfList - 1 ) {
                deleteAtTail();
                return;
            }
            if(outOfBound( index, sizeOfList ) )
                throw std::out_of_range("Exception: Out of Range.");

            int i = 1;
            ListNode *temp = head;
            while( i != index + 1 ) {
                temp = temp->next;
                ++i;
            }
            temp->prev->next = temp->next;
            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
            delete temp;
            --sizeOfList;
        }
};
```

**The main function**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "doubly.hh"

int main() {
    ListNode list;
    for (int i = 0; i != 11; ++i )
        list.create(i);
    list.insertAtHead(54);
    list.insertAtTail(56);
    list.insert(1,67);
    list.deleteAtHead();
    list.deleteAtTail();
    list.erase(1);
    std::cout << list << std::endl;
}
```

On running this code, my output was

```
[67, -921944048, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: Your `deleteAtHead` and `deleteAtTail` functions have a common fatal flaw: What happens if there no, or only one node in the list?

Comment: As for the problem you ask about, I recommend you use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, while at the same time use pen and paper to perform the operations you do in the code (draw boxes for nodes, arrows for *all* pointers, and erase and redraw arrows as you modify pointers).

Comment: Please provide a MRE. I suspect that you try to delete index 1 from a list which only has one entry, i.e. only index 0.

Comment: I have editted the post

Comment: OT: `for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)` is very poor practice: replace with `for (int i = 0; i  <  3; ++i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside `insert` funtcion. The list is being corrupted there.

In your insert function replace the order of these two lines:

```
temp->next = newNode;        // temp->next becomes newMode
temp->next->prev = newNode;  // newMode->prev points to newMode itself
```

They must be:

```
temp->next->prev = newNode;
temp->next = newNode;
```

Comment: @theProgrammer, Yeah, sorry for the first time))) Misread your code then.